# why is the partition not accessible?

Tags: mount, home-directory, fstab, partitioning

I created a new ext4 partition `/dev/sda3` on my system using gparted. I also added following line to the bottom of my fstab: `/dev/sda3    /home    ext4    defaults    0    0` but upon reboot, my user's directory (/home/reg/), doesn't exist! Why not, where has it gone? mount shows me following:

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/104/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=lightdm)
/dev/sda3 on /home type ext4 (rw)
$
```

Please advise!

Comment: what did you use as a line in /etc/fstab?  Sometime a typo in the line causes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you happen to have the 'reg' directory in /home *before* you mounted a new partition over it?

If so, it's simply hidden underneath the new `/dev/sda3` version of `/home`.

Boot off of the CD into a rescue shell, or single user mode, ensure `/dev/sda3` is not mounted, copy your 'reg' homedirectory to somewhere else (with enough space, of course), then reboot again.

Alternatively, comment out (*use `#` at the beginning of the line*) the /home entry of fstab and reboot.  You'll come back up without the `/dev/sda3` home.  Mount `/dev/sda3` on `/mnt` or somewhere, copy 'reg' over, uncomment the line in fstab, and

```
mount -a
```

At this point it's probably best to just reboot again, as you'll likely be logged in as 'reg' and so therefore mounting `/home` over your current $HOME would not be doable.

Of course, if you didn't have reg in `/home` beforehand, feel free to ignore all of the above.

Comment: Why do you have the bit at the end saying `you could ignore all of what I just said' :-)